# How to add new data to state without data getting refreshed in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm rendering data from api, i'm adding load more option to get more data.
But while new data is rendered, component is getting refreshed, as state changes.

How can I solve this ?

This is my code :

```
export  const newDataReducer = (state= InitialState , action = null) => {
    switch(action.type) {
    case types.GET_NEW_DATA:
        let myData;
        myData = _.unionBy(state.data, action.payload.data, "id");
        return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoading:false, data:myData, notification: "Success" });
    }
}
```

My component :

```
_.map(myData, (newData, index) => {
    return (
        newData.id;
    );
});
```

Thank you

Comment: It'd help if you add your component's code, especially the render parts.

Comment: I'm justing mapping & showing the data.

Comment: Don;'t worry about the performance early on. Have you done a perf profile to see if your code is slow?

Answer (score 1):

You can add some logic to [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method to prevent the unwanted rendering.

Comment: @SunilTC if you share what you are doing, perhaps I can help

Comment: shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
        if(nextProps.myData.data !== this.props.myData.data){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: it seems then that `data` has changed as well, at least it doesn't have the same reference any more

Answer (score 0):

You may have a premature optimization situation here. Since the only code to look at here is a reducer, there's no telling how much performance impact your state changes are having in your components. Without having the React component's render code to look at, I can only recommend you to not fix anything. React does a good job of vdom diffing and mostly component rendering doesnt suffer from frequent state changes.

Comment: I'm fetching some data from api, and displaying. when I click load more, I'm fetching some more data from api. This new data is getting added to old data in my reducer. Since I'm displaying the data from reducer state, when new data comes, page is refreshing.

Comment: And what's wrong with that? It'd be much easier for you to share either repo or your component's code to help understand the problem better.